# Can I create a hard dependency between two ECS clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

We have a service that uses two services, a custom java application and a custom kafka build. When releasing a new version of our service, we always tag and push kafka to it's repo and the app to it's repo, with the same version tag. These are part of two separate clusters, due to requiring the application and kafka to run on distinct hosts (not sure if that's the best way to do this ..)

Is there a way I can guarantee that we maintain the same version tag in the container image, for which tag we pull from the repo?

i.e., something like:

```
1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/app:${version}
1234567890.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kafka:${version}
```

And just update `${version}` in one place?

Comment: I haven't seen anything in ECS that establishes a relationship between two separate services.

Answer (score 0):

There's unfortunately no mechanism to directly do this.  You could write a AWS Config rule or periodic lambda that inspects the services and alerts if the versions do not match.